# Layout.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE) crash - if more than one view added

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, adapter

I have a layout which has a hidden layout (LinearLayout which acts as a list) underneath) . If I add one item (by addView) it works. However if I add more than one item it crashes.

```
Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=45; index=-1
 ...
 android.text.StaticLayout.calculateEllipsis (StaticLayout.java:684)
 android.view.View.measure (View.java:17473)
 ....DrawerLayout.onMeasure (....
```

That's my custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.86"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/main_item_background">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dropDownGroupViewLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                   ..../>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainItemTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dropDownLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I inflate it as a view in a certain fragment, where I use addView to add that items to that 'bar' layout.

```
dropDownLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        myAdapter.replaceList(items);
        int count = myAdapter.getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            View view = myAdapter.getView(i, null, null);
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      Item item = (Item) myAdapter.getItem(index);
                     .....
                }});

            dropDownLinearLayout.addView(view);
        }
```

And finally , once I reach dropDownLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); it crashes.

Comment: Exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, which means: 
> The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array. and is irrelevant with `setVisibility(...)` method.

Comment: which index? I just do addView and then setVisibility. It's before I have a chance to click on one of the items

Comment: post adapter code

Comment: I edited my post , and added the adapter. thanks

Comment: Post your `StaticLayout.java` class

Comment: Do you assign memory in class those ids you hide in your xml . you has not added that code which is required those thing you need you did not add that code here .